# iOS 7 game centre runs on simulator but not device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios-simulator, game-center

I'm in the midst of developing an iOS app and I've gotten to the point where it is time to implement some Game Center Leaderboards and Achievements. I followed Apple's programming guide for Game Center and have everything working on both the app-side and the iTunes Connect side including:

- Enabling Game Center in iTunes Connect
- Creating a Game Center enabled app id & provisiong profile
- All needed frameworks have been added to project
- I am a registered apple developer

The problem is when I run the app in the simulator, the game centre user authenticates and everything is fully functional BUT when I install and run the app on any of my devices nothing happens at all! No authentication, no controllers popping up for login or anything! What gives??

Comment: I should add that I've reset my device multiple times, have logged out of Game Center, restarted my computer, restarted Xcode (the whole nine yards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to solve itself. I made some adjustments to the app on the iTunes Connect side and everything began to run as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and it took me a while to work out what it was. GameKit just reported *"The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center"*.

The trick was (for me) on the device to ensure that Game Center was in "Sandbox" mode.

On the device, go to Settings → Game Center. In the "DEVELOPER" section toggle Sandbox. After doing that Game Center worked fine with my app in development.